# C++ ValueError bitset::_M_copy_from_ptr when string and bitset are correct size

Tags: c++

I have a string which should represent a 32 bit integer, so i'm creating a bitset to print the bits:

```
std::string str = rocksDBSlice.ToString();
std::cout << str.length() << std::endl;
std::bitset<32> bits(str);
std::cout << bits.to_string() << std::endl;
```

But at run-time I get:

```
4
ValueError bitset::_M_copy_from_ptr
```

If the string length is 4 why does the bitset throw?

Comment: What is the content of the string?

Comment: @RetiredNinja This is what i'm trying to check but it should be a 4-byte integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor of `std::bitset` with string argument expects the string to contain only `0`s and `1`s. Probably your string contains values like `a` instead of `1100001`. So if you want the 32 bits of 4 bytes of your input string to be put into a `bitset`, you have to convert the string to a sequence of 32 ones and zeros first.